# Running Sum gving Different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my table:

| cust_id | order_id | order_date | total_value | running total | mytotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 7/20/2021 | 100 | 100 | 300 |
| 1 | 3 | 7/21/2021 | 200 | 300 | 300 |

My questions: I am trying to calculate running total:

```
mytotal = sum(total_value)(order by order_date)

running total = sum(total_value)(order by order_id)
```

Why is `mytotal` returning a constant value and not the same value as the `runningtotal`? What is causing this difference?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @asd, please add the code you wrote and the expected output to get better help.

Comment: Hi @asd: please add OVER clause for getting your desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.**

The default window is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which will give you incorrect results if there are two rows with the same ordering (in this case, the same `id`):

```
mytotal = sum(total_value) over (order by order_date rows unbounded preceding)
running total = sum(total_value) over (order by order_id rows unbounded preceding)
```

Answer (score 4):

You must be doing something wrong.  Look at the following:

```
declare @test table (
    cust_id int,
    order_id int,
    order_date date,
    total_value int
    );

INSERT INTO @test VALUES
(1, 2, '2021-07-20', 100),
(1, 3, '2021-07-21', 200);

SELECT cust_id, order_id, order_date, total_value, 
SUM(total_value) OVER (order by order_date) as mytotal,
SUM(total_value) OVER (order by order_id) as running_total
FROM @test;
```

Output:

| cust_id | order_id | order_date | total_value | mytotal | running_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-07-20 | 100 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-07-21 | 200 | 300 | 300 |

As you can see mytotal and running_total are the same.

In order to help you further please show us exactly what you are doing.  To this end please give table creation and insert data statements as I have done for you, together with the exact code you are using, or at least a cutdown version that replicates your problem.  Note that the expressions in your code lack `OVER`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the OVER clause with SUM as below.

```
SELECT 
cust_id, 
SUM (total_value) OVER (ORDER BY cust_id) AS runningTotal,
FROM orders
```